# How can I use if exists with execute?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am unable to create this stored procedure due to syntax error. Is here any one can solve this syntax issue?

```
DROP PROCEDURE REMOTE_DB_CONNECTION_REMOVER;
CREATE PROCEDURE REMOTE_DB_CONNECTION_REMOVER(
    rm_server_user varchar(100),
    rm_server_name varchar(100),
    rm_table varchar(100),
    rm_server_extenstion integer=0
 ) LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP FOREIGN TABLE  %s', rm_table)) THEN
        EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP FOREIGN TABLE  %s', rm_table);
    END IF

    IF EXISTS(EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP USER MAPPING FOR %s SERVER %s',rm_server_user, rm_server_name)) THEN
        EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP USER MAPPING FOR %s SERVER %s',rm_server_user, rm_server_name);
    END IF

    IF EXISTS(EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP SERVER %s', rm_server_name)) THEN
        EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP SERVER %s', rm_server_name);
    END IF
            
END; $$
```

[image]

Comment: Why not simply use `drop foreign table if exists ...`?

Comment: Already try that but showing error >>                                                                    
         ERROR:  column "postgres" does not exist
LINE 1: call REMOTE_DB_CONNECTION_REMOVER(postgres,remote_server10,t...
                                          ^

Comment: Why an IF-statement? You execute 3 different commands, and when they are successful, you execute them again. I'm pretty sure these commands will fail because the object you want to drop doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @SheikhWasiuAlHasib: strings need to be enclosed in single quotes `call ...('postgres', 'remote_server', ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exists` only works together with a `SELECT` statement.

But there is no need for an IF statement at all. All three commands support the `IF EXISTS` option. To include a table name or any identifier in a dynamic SQL using `format()` you should use the `%I` placeholder.

```
DROP PROCEDURE REMOTE_DB_CONNECTION_REMOVER;
CREATE PROCEDURE REMOTE_DB_CONNECTION_REMOVER(
    rm_server_user varchar(100),
    rm_server_name varchar(100),
    rm_table varchar(100),
    rm_server_extension integer=0
 ) LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP FOREIGN TABLE IF EXISTS %I', rm_table);
  EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP USER MAPPING IF EXISTS FOR %I SERVER %I',rm_server_user, rm_server_name);
  EXECUTE FORMAT('DROP SERVER IF EXISTS %I', rm_server_name);
END; $$
```

call remote_db_connection_remover('postgres','remote_server12','student');

Comment: Thanks for answer but It is show this error, issue at postgres user. It said it does not exists for that server>>> postgres=# call remote_db_connection_remover(postgres,remote_server12,student);
ERROR:  column "postgres" does not exist
LINE 1: call remote_db_connection_remover(postgres,remote_server12,s...

Comment: @SheikhWasiuAlHasib: string values need to be enclosed in single quotes: `call ...('postgres', 'remote_server12', 'student');`

Comment: Oh  what a mistake from my end. All done right but sometime silly mistake take my whole day, shame for me.  @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks you so much.